# How save uploaded file? c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, file-upload

I want upload an image file to project's folder but I have an error in my catch:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\project\uploads\logotipos\11111\'.

What am I do wrong? I want save that image uploaded by my client in that folder... that folder exists... ah if I put a breakpoint for folder_exists3 that shows me a true value!

My code is:

```
try
{
    var fileName = dados.cod_cliente;
    bool folder_exists = Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"));
    if(!folder_exists)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"));
    bool folder_exists2 = Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo"));
    if(!folder_exists2)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo"));
    bool folder_exists3 = Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/" + fileName));
    if(!folder_exists3)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/"+fileName));

    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/" + fileName+"/"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Someone knows what I'm do wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: But you are not checking if `\uploads\logotipos\11111\ ` exists just for `uploads/logo/`

Comment: I know that folder exists... in this step I just want save file in that specific folder, when this step already done I will create that verification

Comment: `file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/" + fileName));`

Comment: what is the content of `fileName` and how should your full save filename should be?

Comment: I already test this and the result is the same!

Comment: should be code of my client

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
string targetFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo");
string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, yourFileName);
file.SaveAs(targetPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is the following:

```
bool folder_exists3 = Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/" + fileName));
if(!folder_exists3)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/"+fileName));
```

You check if a directory exists, but you should check if the file exists:

```
File.Exists(....);
```

Comment: but I don't want verify if file exists but yes if folder exists

Comment: then delete that statement. You check the folder with `folder_exists2`

Comment: I need this step for the future upload...and the program don't need create again the same folder

Answer (score 1):

You need filename

```
file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/" + fileName+"/" + your_image_fillename));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last part of the path to save you have an extra "/"

It should be

```
file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/" + fileName);
```

Also you do not have a file extension set.

Comment: unfortunately this don't resolve my problem, I already test this and give to me the same error! :/

Comment: C:\project\uploads\logotipos\11111\' thats your error message right? Well its different than your save as you are looking for \logo not logotipos. also i forgot a bracket - file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/") + fileName);

Comment: I try change to your proposal but don't work :/

file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/logo/") + fileName);

Give to me the same error!

Comment: I tried:

 file.SaveAs(@"C:\" + fileName)

and I could copy... and my answer now is: "Why I can't copy to that specific folder?"

Comment: permissions? What user is your process running as and does that user have read/write persmission on that specific folder?

Comment: I haven't change anything on the windows permissions...what do you thing I need change?