# store images in a folder and retrieve in c# application with Mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a small problem. I have a database called Lease. in this i have a table for customers. So i need to store customer images. it is ok. I used BLOB datatype and the query was successful. But the thing is there will be a lot of customers. I think this makes the database heavy.

So.. I would like to know is there a way to store images in a folder of customer's PC and retrieve it. I think that makes the Database light.

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How save uploaded file? c# mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944645/how-save-uploaded-file-c-sharp-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store files in the client computer, and even if it was possible, what if he delete the file?

The alternative is to save the path of the image in the database and store the file in a different server .

Comment: The thing is if i use Mysql database to store data, the database become so heavy. And i think there is a limit to upload the images.. isn't

Comment: I'm not telling you to store the file in the database, just the path like "~\imgs\myimage.png" and this file can be save in your server that host your application

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944645/how-save-uploaded-file-c-sharp-mvc)

Comment: Thanks. Got it :D