# Save posted image file error on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So, I want to upload an image file and save it to some path. It works on first try, but if want to upload it second time, even after I close the app and run it again, it getting an error

```
The process cannot access the file '..mypath..' because it is being used by another process
```

How do I solve this?

here is my code

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, string text)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = datetime + "_" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            log_file = fileName;
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path); //error

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path);

            bmp = EmbedText(bmp, "Some Text");

            var outputFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/StegoImages/"), fileName); ;
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    bmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }

            string coba = extractText(bmp);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["flag_no_file"] = '1';
            return RedirectToAction("UploadImage");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Can someone help me? maybe my code for upload image is wrong, so how to do it right?

I'm using C# asp .net mvc

sorry for my english..

Comment: you must close the file.

Comment: yeah that's also the problem, how to close the file?

Comment: outputFileName..Close();

Answer (score 1):

I want to know how you call this API request.
But try this code. The image send within the request body here.

```
 [HttpPost]        
 public HttpResponseMessage UploadJsonFile()
 {        
                userID = "any name";    
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                    if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ProfileImages/"+ userID);
                                if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
                                    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");
                                    foreach (FileInfo fil in directory.GetFiles())
                                    {
                                        fil.Delete(); //Delete existing image...
                                    }
                                }
                                Random rnd = new Random();
                                int num = rnd.Next(1, 100);
                                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath +"/"+ num+postedFile.FileName);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return response;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read that post again, it will help you.

[How save uploaded file? c# mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944645/how-save-uploaded-file-c-sharp-mvc)

And also, be sure about your save name isn't exsist and any software doesnt use it.

```
var fileName = datetime + "_" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

Check this line and server path.

Comment: I want to say, maybe there is already same filename in your savepath and some software using it. Otherwise, your save code looks right to me.